# Redirect URLs with a trailing slash to URLs with no trailing slash via htaccess rule with [QSA,L]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

Recently I broke ties with WordPress and migrated all of my site's content to my own custom-made CMS. All works great except for one thing. All previous links to my site's blog posts have a trailing slash. Since none of my current URLs have a trailing slash, the previous links no longer work and my SEO is nearly non-existent. I've been attempting to find an htaccess rule that will redirect all trailing slash URLs to URLs with no trailing slash, but as of now, nothing works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm sure if you posted what you have tried so far people would be more willing to help.  Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this redirect rule as your very first rule to remove trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

## You don't want to remove it 100%for SEO in WordPress.#

#### But this will show you how to if you want that. WordPress "/" fixes. My WordPress [Gist](https://gist.github.com/blueprintmrk/a22792b0afab8f8d894b18690d5722a7)

*Can convert so it's helpful*
Config File: nginx.conf
...

```
location  /mirror/foo/ {
        ...
        rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
        ...
}
```

...

Description WordPress "/" PHP fixes
Retrieve trailing slash string, if blog set for adding trailing slashes.

Conditionally adds a trailing slash if the permalink structure has a trailing slash, strips the trailing slash if not. The string is passed through the `‘user_trailingslashit’` filter. Will remove trailing slash from string, if blog is not set to have them.

Usage

```
<?php user_trailingslashit( $string, $type_of_string ); ?>
```

Parameters

```
$string
(string) (false) URL with or without a trailing slash.
Default: None
$type_of_url
(string) (false) The type of URL being considered (e.g. single, category, etc) for use in the filter.
Default: None
Return Value (string)
```

Adds/removes a trailing slash based on the permalink structure.
codex.wordpress. /Function_Reference/user_trailingslashit

2.
**If you want to add "/"**

```
<?php trailingslashit( $string ) ?>
```

Examples

```
<?php
$path = trailingslashit( '/home/julien/bin/dotfiles' ); 
?>
```

$path will now contain:

```
/home/julien/bin/dotfiles/
```

(Notice the trailing slash)
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/trailingslashit

3.
**This is new**
The most important part of any test is the assertion. An assertion is a comparison between the value you expect to get from the system and the value that you actually get. The very simplest tests may consist of nothing but a single assertion. Example:

```
public function test_trailingslashit_should_add_slash_when_none_is_present() {
    $this->assertSame( 'foo/', trailingslashit( 'foo' ) );
}
```

The `assertSame()` method accepts two parameters: the expected value (in this case, the hardcoded string `'foo/')`, and the actual value (the value returned by `trailingslashit())`.

An annotated list of common assertions can be found below.
https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/automated-testing/writing-phpunit-tests/#assertions

Try these rules:  `(in www.example.com's server block)  rewrite ^/$ http://example.com permanent break; rewrite ^/main(.*)$ http://example.com$1 permanent break; rewrite ^(.*)$` `http://blog.example.com$1 permanent;`  Make sure you reload nginx.
With this config:

1. http://www.example.com/ *redirects to
2. http://example.comt -

   - http://www.example.com/main/something redirects to
3. http://example.com/something -  Everything else redirects to

   - http://blog.example.com/